# Woocommerce Merge featured image and Attachements images in one loop

Tags: woocommerce

in single product page:
How to Merge featured image and Attachments images in one loop.

Featured Image "Product Image":

```
<?php $img_url = $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>

    <img src="<?php  echo $image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
```

Attachements images "Product Gallery" :
global $product;
 $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

```
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
  echo '<img src="'.$image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ).'">';
}
```

Now:
How to create one loop which can get all single product images ?

to be like :

```
foreach( $images as $image_src_url ) 
{
  echo '<img src="'.$image_src_url.'">';
}
```